# keyboard toolbar not showing when presenting a view via .fullScreenCover

Tags: swiftui, toolbar

I've found various other questions with workarounds but none of them seem to work.  I've tried embedding views in NavigationStacks, VStacks etc.  I've pinpointed the issue to having to do with `.fullScreenCover` because if I call the second view via `.sheet`:

```
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSecondView, content: {
            SecondView()
        })
```

then it works.  The other testing I've done has pinpointed the issue I think down to `.onAppear` in the second view.  If I assign focus to the first textfield using a button (see code below), then the keyboard appears with the toolbar.  But if I assign focus via `.onAppear`, then it doesn't:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    
    @State var showSecondView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            
            Button(action: {showSecondView.toggle()}, label: {
                Text("Show Second View")
            })
            
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSecondView, content: {
                    SecondView()
            })
            
            .navigationTitle("First View")
        }
    }
}


struct SecondView: View {
    
    @State var first: String = ""
    @State var second: String = ""
    
    
    @FocusState private var focusedTextfield: TextFields?

    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            
            Button("Show Keyboard") {
                focusedTextfield = .firstTextField
            }
            
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                TextField(text: $first) {
                    Text("first")
                }
                .focused($focusedTextfield, equals: .firstTextField)
                
                TextField(text: $second) {
                    Text("second")
                }
                .focused($focusedTextfield, equals: .secondTextField)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                        Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Prev") })
                        
                        Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Next") })
                        
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {}, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "keyboard.chevron.compact.down")
                        })
                    }
                }
            
                .navigationTitle("Second View")
            
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    focusedTextfield = .firstTextField
                })
        }
    }
    
    
    enum TextFields {
        case firstTextField
        case secondTextField
    }
}
```

Comment: Could not replicate your issue, all works well for me in my tests. On MacOS 14.4, using Xcode 15.3, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews) and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems.

Comment: That's strange....  I'm on MacOS 14.3.1, Xcode 15.2 - tested on iOS 17 devices (real devices and simulator).

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue. It is present in iOS 17.2 when using fullScreenCover only it would seem, and it is not present at all in iOS 16.4 and probably older versions. It is almost surely a bug and you should file a bug report to Apple. [Bug reporting](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)